# Logout delegate not working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-protocols

I have an app that contains a central view controller with 3 child view controllers in a scrollview that represent sections of the app. General flow of my app goes as follows

```
LoginVC -> AppVC [Settings, Inbox, Email]
```

I currently have my logout button in my Settings view controller however the actual logout function needs to be in AppVC. I have tried implementing a delegate but cannot seem to get it working correctly

```
class Settings: UIViewController {
    var delegate: LogoutDelegate?

    @IBAction func logout(_ sender: Any) {
       delegate?.logoutOfApp()
    }
}

protocol LogoutDelegate: class {
    func logoutOfApp() 
}

----------------------------------

class AppVC: UIViewController, LogoutDelegate {
      func logoutOfApp() {
         print("This should be called")
         //Execute logout code
      }
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why my delegate function isnt being called in my AppVC?

**Update**

This is how I set up my child view controllers in a scrollview

```
func setupViews() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let settingsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsVC")
        let inboxVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InboxVC")
        let emailVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmailVC")

        let viewControllers = [settingsVC, inboxVC, emailVC]

        let width = scrollView.bounds.width
        let height = scrollView.bounds.height

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width * 3, height: height)

        var idx = 0

        for vc in viewControllers {
            addChildViewController(vc)
            let originX = CGFloat(idx) * width
            vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
            scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)
            vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            idx += 1
        }

        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: width, y: 0), animated: false)

    }
```

I am not sure where to set my delegate. I have tried to set it inside my for loop `self.delegate = vc` but always get the same error of not being able to set the delegate

Comment: Where do you set delegate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never set the delegate, otherwise the delegate will always be `nil` and `delegate?.logoutOfApp()` won't be executed.

In `AppVC`, you need to do something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    settings.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: I see that now, however I am having issues setting the delegate to itself. I have all my childview controllers displaying in a scrollView I am not segueing to them or anything like that. I cant seem to set my delegate correctly I always get the same error cannot set UIViewController to LogoutDelegate

Comment: Make sure `AppVC` inherits from `LogoutDelegate`